# Find and replace a digit except first one in PHP

Tags: php

I want to replace an certain digit from a string but don't change the first digit in php.

For example, change all 4 to 5:

```
34 => 35
148 => 158
2449 => 2559
15540 => 15550

43 => 43 (Don't change start 4)
450 => 450 (Don't change start 4)
4540 => 4550 (only change second 4)
```

Comment: save first char, replace 4->5 in the remaining part and concatenate with saved first char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$a="4540";//As described in question its an string but it can even be a no auto type conversion will do the rest

$tem=$a[0];

$a=str_ireplace('4', '5', $a);

$a[0]=$tem;

echo $a;//or do what ever you want with $a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ex1 = '34';
$ex2 = '4540';

echo $ex1{0} . str_replace(4, 5, substr($ex1, 1)); // 35
echo $ex2{0} . str_replace(4, 5, substr($ex2, 1)); // 4550
```

Must be string - convert to string first then convert back to int if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$no="445486";
for($i=1;$i<strlen($no);$i++){
    if($no[$i]=="4")
        $no[$i]="5";
}
echo $no;
```